# How to do multiple interfaces in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

How can I do the following things in Objective C (the examples below are in pseudo-code):

1. interface A extends B, C
2. interface A

interface B

class X inplemements A, B

3.
interface A

class X implements A

class Y implements A

interface B

class Z extends Y implements B

thanks!

Comment: Do you mean interface as in @interface or as in protocols (aka @protocol)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sounds like homework, you should take the first move: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C

look at 2.2 Interfaces and implementations

MyClass extends Class

```
 @interface MyClass : Class { }
 @end
```

MyClass extends Class implements Interface1 & Interface2

```
 @interface MyClass : Class <Interface1, Interface2> {}
 @end
```