# How can I declare interface in AppDelegate.h in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I'm using React Native to make an iOS Application.

I need to add some code to `AppDelegate.h` file.

However, after searching about this, I realized that it's impossible to declare two interfaces at the same time.

How can I integrate these two interfaces?

```c
// here's the code in AppDelegate.h

@interface AppDelegate : UMAppDelegateWrapper <RCTBridgeDelegate>

    @property (nonatomic, strong) UMModuleRegistryAdapter *moduleRegistryAdapter;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;


@end


@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, AppsFlyerTrackerDelegate>
@end
```

Comment: try it: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226144/how-to-do-multiple-interfaces-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suposing that **UMAppDelegateWrapper** is a subclass of **UIResponder**, you can merge both as follows:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UMAppDelegateWrapper <UIApplicationDelegate, AppsFlyerTrackerDelegate,RCTBridgeDelegate>

    @property (nonatomic, strong) UMModuleRegistryAdapter *moduleRegistryAdapter;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;


@end
```